# CSS text-align: left not working as it should

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have large amount of data and to view a result which generate through a search I use a table. As per a request 5 more columns was added into the table and after adding these columns I can see that data inside table is not aligned properly as they should be according to  `text-align: left` . I have modified my CSS in various ways but still couldn't fix this.

This is the **css**

```
           input{
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            #searchResults tbody tr{
                text-transform: uppercase; 
            }
            .table-fixed thead {
                font-size: 14px;
                width: 6720px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .table-fixed tbody {
                overflow-y: auto;
                width: 6720px;
                max-height:68vh;                    
            }
            .table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
                border-bottom-width: 0;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
                border-bottom-width: 0;
                text-align: left;
                color:white;
            }
            .scrollDivForTable{
                overflow-x: scroll;
            }
            .col-xs-1{
                width: 210px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            tr{
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            tr:hover {background-color: #CFD8DC;}
            tr:nth-child(odd):hover { background-color:#CFD8DC ;}
            tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #f2f2f2}
            td{
                font-size: 13px;
                color: black;
               vertical-align:center;
            }
            .nav-pills li{
                width: 49%;
                background-color: #cccccc;
                font-size: 13px
            }
            .nav-pills li:hover{
                background-color: #666666;
            }
```

This is the HTML table

```
 <div class="panel-body" id="searchResultsPanel" >
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="scrollDivForTable">
                                            <table class="table table-fixed">
                                                <thead >
                                                    <tr style="background-color:#757575;"> 
                                                    <th class="col-xs-1">Index</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">CDC No</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Added Date</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Passport No</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Surname</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Initials</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Rank</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Land Phone No</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Mobile No</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Confirm Last  Contact</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Email Address</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Facebook Address</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Skype ID</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Last Contacted Date</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Next Contacted Date</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Previous Wages</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Expecting Wages</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Companies</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Available Date</th>
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Job Status</th>
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">COC Type</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Experience</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Date of Birth</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Address</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">City</th>
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Friends</th>
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Remarks</th>
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Type of Nationality</th>
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Nationality</th>
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Contacted By</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">To be interviewed on</th> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Interviewed By</th> 
                                            </tr>
                                                    </thead>

                                                <tbody>
                                                    <?php
                                                   //var_dump($$sqlSearch);
                                                   if($sqlSearch != null) {
                                                    $resultSearch = $conn->query($sqlSearch);
                                                    $index = ((int) $pageNumber - 1) * $numOfDataPerPage;
                                                    if ($resultSearch->num_rows > 0) {
                                                        // output data of each row
                                                        while ($rowSearch = $resultSearch->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                            ++$index;
                                                            ?>
                                                            <tr class="recordRow">
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt1" ><?php echo $index; ?></td> 
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt2"><?php echo $rowSearch['cdc']; ?></td> 
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt3"><?php echo $rowSearch['add_date']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt4"><?php echo $rowSearch['passport']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt5"><?php echo $rowSearch['surname']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt6"><?php echo $rowSearch['initials']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt7 <?php echo $rowSearch['rank']; ?>"><?php echo getValueFrmId("rank", "rank", "idrank", $rowSearch['rank'], "No Rank") ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt8"><?php echo $rowSearch['telephone']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt9"><?php echo $rowSearch['mobile']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt10"><i class="fa fa-mouse-pointer" aria-hidden="true" style=" text-align: left;"></i> Double click to Confirm</td> 
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt11" style=" text-align: left;"><?php echo $rowSearch['email']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt12"><?php echo $rowSearch['fb']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt13"><?php echo $rowSearch['skype']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt14" style=" text-align: left;"><?php if(($rowSearch['last_contacted_date']=='1800-01-01') ||($rowSearch['last_contacted_date']=='0000-00-00') ||($rowSearch['last_contacted_date']=='')){ echo "<p style='color:red;'><i class='fa fa-phone '></i> &nbsp; Not yet Contacted</p>";}else{   echo ($rowSearch['last_contacted_date']." at ".$rowSearch['last_cont_time']) ;} ?></td> 
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt15"><?php if(($rowSearch['next_date'] =='1800-01-01')){ echo "";}else if(($rowSearch['next_date'] =='0000-00-00')){echo "";}else{ echo $rowSearch['next_date'];} ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt16"><?php echo $rowSearch['pre_wages']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt17"><?php echo $rowSearch['exp_wages']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt18 <?php echo $rowSearch['companies']; ?>"><?php echo getValueListFrmId("companies", "name", "idcompanies", $rowSearch['companies'], ""); ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt19"><?php if(($rowSearch['ava_date'] =='1800-01-01')){ echo "";}else if(($rowSearch['next_date'] =='0000-00-00')){echo "";}else{ echo $rowSearch['ava_date'];} ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt20 <?php echo $rowSearch['job_status']; ?>"><?php echo getValueFrmId("job_status", "status", "idjob_status", $rowSearch['job_status'], "No Status") ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt21 <?php echo $rowSearch['coc_type']; ?>"><?php echo getValueFrmId("coc_type", "coc_type", "idcoc_type", $rowSearch['coc_type'], "No COC Type") ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt22 <?php echo $rowSearch['experience']; ?>"><?php echo getValueListFrmId("vessel_types", "vessel_types", "idvessel_types", $rowSearch['experience'], "No Experience"); ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt23"><?php if(($rowSearch['dob'] =='1800-01-01')){ echo "";}else if(($rowSearch['next_date'] =='0000-00-00')){echo "";}else{ echo $rowSearch['dob'];} ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt24"><?php echo $rowSearch['address']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt25"><?php echo $rowSearch['city']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt26"><?php echo $rowSearch['friends']; ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt27"><?php echo $rowSearch['remarks']; ?></td> 
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt28 <?php echo $rowSearch['typeOfNationality']; ?> "><?php echo getValueFrmId("type_of_nationality", "name_of_nationality", "id_type_of_nationality", $rowSearch['typeOfNationality'], ""); ?></td>
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt29 <?php echo $rowSearch['nationality']; ?>" ><?php echo getValueFrmId("countries", "nationality", "num_code", $rowSearch['nationality'], ""); ?></td> 
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt30 <?php echo $rowSearch['contacted_by']; ?> "><?php echo getValueFrmId("user", "username", "iduser", $rowSearch['contacted_by'], ""); ?></td> 
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt31 "><?php echo $rowSearch['to_be_interviewed_on']; ?></td> 
                                                                <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt32 <?php echo $rowSearch['to_be_interviewed_by']; ?> "><?php echo getValueFrmId("superintendents", "superintendent_name", "superintendent_id", $rowSearch['to_be_interviewed_by'], ""); ?> </td> 

                                                            </tr>
                                                            <?php
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    } else {
                                                        ?>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="col-xs-1" colspan="32">No Record Found</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <?php
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

This is the snap of the result

[image: snap of the result]

This is the html output

```
<div class="panel-body" id="searchResultsPanel" >
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="scrollDivForTable">
                                                <table class="table table-fixed">
                                                    <thead >
                                                        <tr style="background-color:#757575;"> 
                                                        <th class="col-xs-1">Index</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">CDC No</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Added Date</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Passport No</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Surname</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Initials</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Rank</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Land Phone No</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Mobile No</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Confirm Last  Contact</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Email Address</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Facebook Address</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Skype ID</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Last Contacted Date</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Next Contacted Date</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Previous Wages</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Expecting Wages</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Companies</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Available Date</th>
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Job Status</th>
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">COC Type</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Experience</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Date of Birth</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Address</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">City</th>
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Friends</th>
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Remarks</th>
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Type of Nationality</th>
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Nationality</th>
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Contacted By</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">To be interviewed on</th> 
                                                            <th class="col-xs-1">Interviewed By</th> 
                                                </tr>
                                                        </thead>

                                                    <tbody>
                                                                                                                        <tr class="recordRow">
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt1" >1</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt2">000001</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt3">2019-06-10</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt4">N02025</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt5">new namw</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt6">fg</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt7 53">MMT</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt8"></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt9">454545</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt10"><i class="fa fa-mouse-pointer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Double click to Confirm</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt11">dfdasfhg@cc.com</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt12">dfdf</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt13">ddff</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt14">2019-06-14 at 08:51:31</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt15">2019-07-23</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt16">450</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt17">500</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt18 79,">A N Nomikcs</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt19">2019-06-15</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt20 4">Active</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt21 3">Eng Class V</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt22 22,">Barge</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt23">1983-03-01</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt24">djhdfghsshdgsh</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt25">vghfvhgfh</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt26">no friendsvjhg</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt27">ffg dgd</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt28 1 ">Sri Lankan</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt29 144" >Sri Lankan</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt30 1 ">super</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt31 ">2019-06-20</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt32 6 ">Superintendent 02 </td> 

                                                                </tr>
                                                                                                                                <tr class="recordRow">
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt1" >2</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt2">018395</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt3">2019-04-25</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt4">N2060876</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt5">Perera</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt6">A.A.Sugath  Anton Jayalal</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt7 20">MOTO</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt8"></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt9">0726377797</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt10"><i class="fa fa-mouse-pointer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Double click to Confirm</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt11"></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt12"></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt13"></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt14"><p style='color:red;'><i class='fa fa-phone '></i> &nbsp; Not yet Contacted</p></td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt15"></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt16">0</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt17">0</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt18 4,">Anna</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt19"></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt20 4">Active</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt21 0">No COC Type</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt22 2,9,">General Cargo Ship,Oil Tanker</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt23"></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt24">No.28/3,Alehiwatta Rd,Walisara,Ragama.</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt25">Ragama</td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt26"></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt27">MMM Application received on 04.05.16.</td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt28  "></td>
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt29 " ></td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt30  "></td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt31 "></td> 
                                                                    <td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt32  "> </td> 

                                                                </tr>
```

Comment: Hi, try to put the html output without php to help us to reproduce the setting

Comment: a demo in a codepen would be nice. It would help us debug. :)

Comment: don't use a codepen!!!!! Use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Putting the code in a codepen without putting it **in the question itself** is offtopic for stackoverflow. Since you're already required to put the code in the question itself then put it in a snippet.

Comment: You have to post the browser output in this case, not the PHP code, since we don't have your database! We don't know even the query you are running...

Comment: Guys thanks for commenting. Ill update my question with the HTML output

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Check out the data from your source, it looks like it is passing white space before the value.

Comment: I have added the html output so can you guys check now

Comment: You've got some strange stuff in the `class=""` string that might be causing some of the issues. Example: `<td class="col-xs-1 rcdRwDt rcdRwDt22 2,9,">` [Classes can't start with a number](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/class/) and the commas shouldn't be there.

Comment: even with your HTML output, I cant re-create the same issue.